# Android Advertising ID Compliance check

Tags: android, admob, adsense, ads, google-advertising-id

One of my Apps has been removed because not compliant with the new Android Advertising ID policy. This App had a simple AdMob/Google AdSense banner.

I would like to know how to check if my other Apps (using AdMob/Google AdSense) are compliant with the Android Advertising ID policy. How can I do that?

Thanks